# infer function return type, knowing the value of one property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a way to do it? I know, that I can if/else or switch my "type" property to get a specific interface. But can I make something like it with function's (or method's) return value?

```
interface test1 {
    type: 'test1'
}

interface test2 {
    type: 'test2'
}

type unType = test1 | test2;

//i know property "type"'s value
//can i somehow use this information to infer specific type (test1 or test2)
function whichType<T>(typeValue): T {

    return null;
}

const tt1 = whichType<unType>('test1');// should be interface test1
const tt2 = whichType<unType>('test2');// should be interface test2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use overloads as TJ Crowder suggests, and this is probably the best solution if you just have a few interfaces, as it's simple to write an understand.

A more general solution would be to use the `Extract` conditional type to extract the type based on the string passed in:

```
interface test1 { type: 'test1' }

interface test2 { type: 'test2' }

type unType = test1 | test2;

function whichType<K extends unType['type']>(typeValue: K): Extract<unType, {type: K}> {
    return null!;
}

const tt1 = whichType('test1'); // test1
const tt2 = whichType('test2'); // test2
```

A solution that would work for any union can be build but it requires you to use function currying because typescript does not support partial type parameter inference:

```
function whichType<T extends { type: string}>() {
    return function <K extends T['type']>(typeValue: K): Extract<T, {type: K}> {
        return null!;
    }
}

const tt1 = whichType<unType>()('test1'); // test1
const tt2 = whichType<unType>()('test2'); // test2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from a type perspective if you're really using literals when calling `whichType` by using function overloading:

```
interface test1 {
    type: 'test1'
}

interface test2 {
    type: 'test2'
}

type unType = test1 | test2;

function whichType(typeValue: 'test1'): test1;
function whichType(typeValue: 'test2'): test2;
function whichType(typeValue: string): unType {
    switch (typeValue) {
        case 'test1':
            return <test1>null;
        case 'test2':
            return <test2>null;
        default:
            throw new Error(`Unknown type ${typeValue}`);
    }
}

const tt1 = whichType('test1'); // tt1's type is test1
const tt2 = whichType('test2'); // tt2's type is test2
```

[On the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20test1%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'test1'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20test2%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20type%3A%20'test2'%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20unType%20%3D%20test1%20%7C%20test2%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20whichType(typeValue%3A%20'test1')%3A%20test1%3B%0D%0Afunction%20whichType(typeValue%3A%20'test2')%3A%20test2%3B%0D%0Afunction%20whichType(typeValue%3A%20any)%3A%20unType%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20switch%20(typeValue.type)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'test1'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%3Ctest1%3Enull%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20case%20'test2'%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%3Ctest2%3Enull%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20default%3A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20Error(%60Unknown%20type%20%24%7BtypeValue.type%7D%60)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20tt1%20%3D%20whichType('test1')%3B%20%2F%2F%20tt1's%20type%20is%20test1%0D%0Aconst%20tt2%20%3D%20whichType('test2')%3B%20%2F%2F%20tt2's%20type%20is%20test2)

As you can see from the code comment, you'll still need runtime logic to handle it at runtime.

To allow non-literal strings in calls to `whichType`, you'd need to add another overload:

```
function whichType(typeValue: string): unType;
```

...and then deal with the fact that you don't know the type. :-|

[On the playground][2]

[2]: function whichType(typeValue: string): unType;